# Failed cascading delete detaches entities from local cache

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, cascade, cascading-deletes

When a user unknowingly attempts to delete an entity that has children it fails because breeze does not currently support cascading deletes, which is expected.

But a side effect of this action is that it detaches entities from the local cache. So from the user interface it appears that those entities have been deleted.

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Is there a straight forward way of checking if the entity has children (ex. hasChildren()) and prevent the user from getting into this state on the client side?

Comment: Sounds like a design issue - Breeze is not your database, either your database doesn't support cascading deletes or you have a design flaw around deleting.  Your question 'is this expected behavior?' is answered yes, when you let a user detach an entity and accept the changes that is what will happen.  Is there a straightforward way to check for children?  - yes, check for children in your JavaScript before authorizing the save.

Comment: I came to this question with the exact same issue. the problem with letting the database do the cascade deletes is that the foreign keys to the parent entity are required attributes, so the client chokes whenever breeze attempts to update the children with null values for those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this an expected behavior?

   - Yes it is. When you delete a row. logically, it should disappear from the user's point of view, even though it may fail during the save. Any failure can be avoided by handling it in the savechanges fail method.
2. Is there a straight forward way of checking if the entity has children (ex. hasChildren()) and prevent the user from getting into this state on the client side?

Yes there is..
Let's say you have a parent "customer" and it's children "orders"
your code may be something like this:

```
if (customer.orders()) return 'Your message';
else
return customer().entityAspect.setDeleted();
```

However, I agree with PW Kad.. I would go for the the database choice and sit back.

If you are using SQL server then you might want to set a delete cascade rule from there.

For the sake of customer-orders, expand "orders" table; you'll find the FK constraint under "Keys".Right Click then Modify. a dialog will show; expand "Insert and Update specification"change the "Delete Rule" to "Cascade" You can set the update rule as well..